# How can I install my installed linux on another hardware too?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, configuration

It's my state: 
I installed some apps on a linux server(ubuntu).
Apps stack are development tools:
-some of Atlassian product
-SVN, USVN
-Maven, Artifactory
-Tomcat & ...

My problem:
I want to create a bootable dvd to be able to restore same state(OS, configuration and apps) on another hardware(server).

Some notes:
I prefer ubuntu but my linux can be a different distributions if needed.
w
I prefer final result (bootable dvd) be simple and easy to use as installing a linux(ubuntu).
I prefer a bootable DVD but if it's not possible, any other solution like partial backup/package even if needed to install first OS and then apply the package/backup/... can be good.

Finally:
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Ubuntu and have done this in a few different ways.

**Copying Just Your Data**
This is the safest way, because you'll avoid problems with different proprietary setups - such as nVidia X configuration vs ATI X config. Simply move your home directory onto the target machine and install your same linux distro onto this machine. Check with your distro to see if it will leave the existing files on the disk alone, Ubuntu will not touch stuff not named `/usr`, `/etc`, and more. This will have your user configurations, which will allow your applications to be configured the same.

You can use Synaptic to generate a package download script from one machine to another.

**Copying the partition**
I've had success directly copying one partition to another, as long as the architecture was the same - so no switching from 32-bit to 64-bit or vice-versa. You may have to do some hacking to get nVidia vs ATI or other X configuration differences, or remove some packages for hardware that isn't already installed.

`dpkg-reconfigure` on Debian/Ubuntu helps with getting packages to adapt to a new environment.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Remastersys](http://klikit.pbworks.com/Remastersys).  From their FAQ :

> Remastersys is a tool that can be used to do 2 things with an existing Klikit or Ubuntu or derivative installation.
>
> 1. It can make a full system backup including personal data to a live cd
>    or dvd that you can use anywhere and
>    install.
> 2. It can make a distributable copy you can share with friends.  This will
>    not have any of your personal user
>    data in it.

The first option seems to be what you want.

Comment: @donamir If it is your solution, you should click the green check mark to indicate it.

Comment: No, it just seems but are not!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/). I currently use this as part of a disaster recovery plan, but it is capable of first pulling an image of the template computer, then installing it on any number of other machines. The version I use is CloneZilla Live, which is a bootable DVD ISO image.

You will have to boot the template machine from this DVD, then it will walk you through the steps to save your image to network, USB drive, etc... Then, of course, boot the target machine from the same DVD, and run the restore side of things. Of course, you'll have to take into account your hardware configurations, and you'll have to do basic customizing of each clone (hostnames and IPs, etc...) but this should get you 99% of the way there.

Good luck!